# Unknown output of a C++ code defining classes and objects

Tags: c++, class

I have the following piece of code:

In the last line, it prints a strange value of 6295680. What is that ?!

```
#include<iostream>

#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;
    
class c{
  private:
        int a;
  public:
        c(int b=1): a(b) {}
        
        int f() {
            return a++;
        }
        int g(){
            cout << a << endl;
        }
};

int main(){
    c ob(20);
    cout<<ob.f() << endl;
    //cout<< ob.a << endl;
    cout << ob.g()<< endl;
}
```

Comment: `int g()` That says `g()` is returning an `int`, but there is no return value in the code. The compiler would normally issue a warning about that. Do not ignore it.

Comment: Thanks @dxiv. Got you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it prints a strange value of 6295680. What is that ?!

It is result of undefined behaviour.

You've declared that the function returns `int`. The function doesn't return a value, nor does it throw an exception. As the consequence, the behaviour of the program is undefined.